# wxPython: maximize Frame while disable resizing (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, frame, maximize

On Linux, how do you disable re-sizing, but at the same time maximize the interface to begin with?

I have tried the following but it is not maximized:

```
style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

style = wx.MAXIMIZE | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER
```

EDIT:

Tried Maximize() with resize disabled, still nothing. My versions: Linux, Python 2.4, wxPython 2.8.12.1

(style = wx.MAXIMIZE works for Windows, but not for Linux)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You just forgot to call Maximize(). See below:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class NoResizeFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    This frame cannot be resized. It can only be minimized, maximized
    and closed
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="No Resize", style=no_resize)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.Show()
        self.Maximize()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = NoResizeFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You might find this tutorial of mine useful for better understanding frame style flags:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/06/wxpython-101-using-frame-styles/

Or this slightly older tutorial on maximizing:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-making-your-frame-maximize-or-full-screen/

Comment: You cannot use self.Maximize() if resize is not allowed. I just tried your code on Linux, Python 2.4, wxPython 2.8.12.1

Comment: oh...sorry. I didn't realize you wanted to maximize AND disable resizing. Since those are mutually exclusive operations, you cannot do that. The best you could do would be to ask the OS what the monitor resolution is and set the frame's size accordingly.

Comment: I cannot find any samples to get monitor resolution for both Linux and Windows. I am using Python 2.4

Comment: But the interface does not start off centered. I guess diabling resize makes Centre() and Maximize() useless too